# Take picture fails in dual camera mode

Tags: android, android-camera

I'm having some issues when I'm in dual shot mode.
This is what I've got so far:

- back camera mode - works perfectly
- front camera mode - works perfectly
- parallel camera mode (full back preview + small window front preview) - works perfectly on the devices that support accessing both cameras at the same time (like Samsung S4).

The problem is: while having both previews display, I call takePicture() method on BOTH cameras. It works perfectly on devices like Samsung S4 and HTC M8, but on LG G3 the takePicture() on the back camera just doesn't work. It doesn't even enter any of the callbacks. The front picture is taken correctly, but the back camera isn't, and then it freezes and I get a camera error 100, while the front camera keeps working fine.

I mention that **all the above devices** (S4, M8, and G3) **support parallel cameras**. The problem is only at G3 when I want to takePicture.

I've also tested on Nexus 5 which does not support and I've implemented a different approach which works great (basically, I take pictures one at a time).

Comment: nice idea to take picture from both camera at same time (y)

Comment: Thanks, however, this bug makes it not stable. I don't even get a callback saying "Hey, take picture has failed!". Nothing

Comment: In the old Android, I 've tried it before, but at that time, you can call prepare/preview camera only one at a time. If you open front, then you can't open back, and that's why in that time it won't be success. I'm doubt that G3 still didn't provide this function to support both camera

Comment: I know that old devices don't support parallel camera. However, if the device has two hardware image processors, then the cameras can be opened and display preview at the same time. Nexus 5 for example cannot, but the G3 can. As I said, I have two instances of the two cameras (front and back) and display preview, it's the takePicture(..) method that fails. I've tested it with the native camera app and it works

Comment: How do you call them at same time? `c1.take..(...); c2.take(...);` What have you tried? reversing them? calling `c2.take` from one of the `c1` callbacks - not ideal, but could give hint to problem.

Comment: Yes, this is how I call takePicture. I've also tried calling the second method after a period of time (1000ms). I've also tried reversing them, but it doesn't work

Comment: Did you use `Handler.postDelayed` when you tried taking after 1 second? What time delay does it start to work after? 10 seconds, 30? or never

Comment: Never. And I figured out WHY it doesn't work, I just don't know how to fix it. Basically, if there is another camera preview ON TOP of another, the preview from the back won't be able to take photo. If I call stop preview on the one at the top, then the back one works. The problem is, it takes a lot of time to do that, it would take almost more than 5 seconds to take a picture (stop preview, take picture, start preview, take picture, then combine the pictures in the background, then show display of the picture).

Comment: It still bugs me that on some devices it works great when taking pictures at the same time. Would have been better not to work at all :)

Comment: Some variations of S4 were built with Snapdragon 800. Which SoC did your device have?